# Lightweight codeigniter/php cms that easily plugs into site code

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I have another codeigniter CMS suggestion question.  Pretty much I am just looking for a CMS that allows my client to easily add in content that doesn't necessarily need to be tied into a page.  I pretty much want a MYSQL database with a gui that allows the client to upload content to certain tables in the db.  I don't want any themes attached to the cms as the site code will all be custom built and I would prefer to write all the db calls to pull data for specific pages.  I just need a way for the client to easily upload data to a table where I can create a model to pull the data.

I have heard of FuelCMS, Ionize, and PyroCMS but all these seem like they have too much.  I am looking for a pretty barebones db that has a gui and good documentation for the api's.  That's all.

Thanks!

Comment: PHPMyAdmin? Maybe too much power for your client.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking about that... probably too much power/confusion for the client.  I might just end up building a small gui page that allows for limited uploading or content/images

Comment: sounds pretty basic. shouldn't take too long to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wouldn't think of ExpressionEngine as "lightweight" but from the perspective that you are speaking, it is...

It allows complete control of content separate from any design's or concepts of "pages".  It's power is that you define "objects" or channels that contain specific information that you then take and construct the pages around.  Channels are a more user friendly concept of the MYSQL tables you're talking about.

**<strike>Downside</strike>You get good support because** it's not free, <strike>but</strike> and worth the money.

It's module development pattern is familiar if you are a codeigniter developer also.